# Is it possible to submit a GET form to two different views with two buttons?

Tags: html, django, forms, get

I have a get form that works well on one view.

```
http://myurl.com/myapp/filter_objects/?risk__worktask=1&craft=3
```

I have another view to export this filtered list to pdf. For now i'm storing the results in session and accessing list from there in my pdf view, but ideally i would like to pass the filter parameters from the GET form directly to the export_to_pdf view.

Is that possible in django ? [ to have a given GET form send to two different urls with two submit buttons ? Would be great !

Thanks !

Here's my form

```
<form method="get">

<div class="well">
  <h4 style="margin-top: 0">Filter Objects</h4>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            {{ filter.form.risk__worktask.label_tag }}
            {% render_field filter.form.risk__worktask class="form-control" %}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            {{ filter.form.craft.label_tag }}
            {% render_field filter.form.craft class="form-control" %}
        </div>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
    </button>

</div>
```

```
<div class="well">
  <h4 style="margin-top: 0">Filtered Ratings: {{ filter.qs.count }}</h4>
  <a href="{% url 'myapp:export_ratings_to_pdf_by_worktask' %}">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Export Filtered List ({{ filter.qs.count }} items)</button>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't u use the **formaction=** tag attribute in your button to override the form action?

```
<form method="get" action="firstView">
  <input ...
  <input ...
  <button ...>Submit to first view</button>
  ..
  ..
  <button formaction="{% url 'myapp:secondView' %}" ...>Submit to second view</button>
</form>
```

It is a HTML5 attribute but it is supported by all the major browsers.

[FormAction browser support](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/13-formaction.html)

Comment: This works ! However not perfectly as i had to hardcode the target url of the formaction in the second button, without using the nice django url helpers. Any idea what would be the correct syntax for that?

Comment: What do you mean by hardcoding?, you can easily use the template `{% url ... %}` tag in the `formaction` value to make it dynamic. same as u did with `href`.

Example: `<button formaction={%url "myapp:export_ratings_to_pdf_by_worktask" %}>`

Comment: Works really well thanks ! I'll accept answer and edit it to add the final version with url tag. Thanks !